# atebits Twitter fast scrolling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm looking to implement the same technique used by atebits in the Twitter app to achieve very fast UITableView scrolling,

http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

But, due to Tweetie being purchased by Twitter, atebits has ceased to exist and the sample code has gone, along with all of the css for the site.

Does anybody have a copy of the sample code or a different resource on implementing this method of drawing UITableViewCell's into one view?

Comment: I don't think you need this anymore; Apple's table suite sample code now includes this technique. Only it's modernized.

Comment: [Here's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318) the link to the Sample Code

Comment: For anybody looking for the original writeup, it's available on [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20100322222950/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) (donate to them if it helped you!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Available here: https://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell

He is simply doing his own drawing in the drawRect: method inherited from UIView. See also [Tricks for improving iPhone UITableView scrolling performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance/1352594#1352594)

Comment: I thought there would be something more special.